# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'instance' and 'float'

Tags: python, python-2.7

This code is too long to post the whole thing so hopefully the problem is just contained in this loop, but I'm really confused about what's wrong here. I have this loop:

```
 if index == 1:
         mag_diffs = []
         counter = 0

         while (image_objects[counter].magr_value > -6.0) and (image_objects[counter].magr_value < -4.0) and (counter < 5):
             mag_diff = (image_objects[counter].magr_value - new_s_objects[counter].magr)
             print 'mag_diff is:'
             print mag_diff
             mag_diffs.append(mag_diff)
             counter +=1


         mag_diffs.sort()
         mag_offset = np.median(mag_diffs)
```

and it runs into an error later in the code when I try to call it here:

```
 sextractor_mr.append((new_s_objects[index].magr + mag_offset))
```

It gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sextractor_reader.py", line 272, in <module>
    sextractor_mr.append((new_s_objects[index].magr + mag_offset))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

But I also figured out that the while loop condition is never being met (which it should be, five times) so when I comment out the while loop and remove the indentations, so that it just does what's in the while loop one time, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sextractor_reader.py", line 252, in <module>
    mag_diff = (image_objects[counter].magr_value - new_s_objects[counter].magr)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'instance' and 'float'
```

I've tried to look up the error messages and haven't found anything similar to my situation. I'm not very comfortable with classes so I think it has something to do with trying to work with those. Hopefully the error is contained in what I gave you but the code really is too long to post all of it (like 1000 lines).

edit: okay it is something wrong with what I have here. I printed
    image_objects[0].magr_value
above the if statement and it returned

```
<__main__.SDSS_object instance at 0x10bd4d7a0>
```

which is not at all what I want. I want a float with a value. I thought that was how you called classes though.

Comment: When the code *is too long to post the whole thing*, the correct method is not post part of it, and *hopefully the problem is just contained in this loop*, but post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The first error, `index` is out of range, it exceeds the highest index of the list, or is negative.  Remember that the highest index number is one less than the number of elements.  So if you only have one element, `index` should be zero. The second error is because you are trying to subtract `magr` from `magr_value` - it's probably a typo when you missed the `_value` off the end.

Comment: Okay I will try that and repost the question later if I don't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to give us some more details to give you specifics, but I can decode the error message for you. It's telling you that `image_objects[counter].magr_value` is not a numeric type. It's some other type (`instance` specifically) that can't have numbers subtracted from it. Like Yu Hao pointed out, we need a complete example to help you more.